# How to make a link in RichTextBox clickable

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am currently using WinForms Application and it seems that I have ran into a problem. I have a button that when pressed it outputs a link in a RichTextBox. However, the link is highlighted in blue but when I click it does not open in my browser. Here is the code(Note that `https://something.com/` represents an actual link.):

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project 
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "https://something.com/" + textBox1.Text;

        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [RichTextBox.LinkClicked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.linkclicked?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Thanks, how can I create an event handler for LinkClicked event?

Comment: Select the control and press `F4` to switch to the `Properties` window, click the lighting button to list the `Events`, find the `LinkClicked` event and double click it to add the handler, in the handler add this line to run the link `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.LinkText);.`

Comment: Or just like what Jimi told you in your [second/third](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61927805/10216583) question in this serious. I lost the count.

Comment: I mean **series**.