# How to conncet the event handler with the LinkClicked event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using winforms and I am trying to make a link in a rich text box clickable and be able to launch in a browser. I want to know how I can connect the event handler with the LinkClicked event

```
        private void Link_Clicked(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.LinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {         
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.LinkText);
    }
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: `richTextBox1.LinkClicked += this.Link_Clicked;` Or use the Properties panel (click the lightning bolt icon, find the LinkClicked event and use the Combo to select an existing handler).